# How to make a game object rotate around its Axis in Unity?

Tags: unity

Ok So i making this simple platformer with a ball. So basically i have A pickup / Collectible that is a Coin. I want the coin till it gets collected by the ball to keep rotating around it axis . Also I know I could do this by adding a Animation but I would prefer doing it Via A C# Script. So please if anybody knows how then Tell me.
Thanks

Comment: -1 "This question does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rotating around the x axis, you can use this code:

```
float speed =5f;
void Update () {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right *speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```